# jQuery.ajax returning empty response text in IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am running into this wierd situation where I make $.ajax() call to retrieve a text file containing dictionary objects.

```
var promise = $.ajax( {
            url : path,
            beforeSend : function (xhr) {
                xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=" + charset );
            },
            cache : false,
            method : 'POST',
            dataType: "text"    
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        //return async ? promise : req.responseText;
        return promise;
```

where the path points to some spell checker dictionary files ".aff" or ".dic" files. These files contain text.

I see the following response in IE11, that the request is successful and returned successful response. But the *data* in the **done** function is empty.

[image: IE11 network inspector]

Anyone faced similar issues. Only in IE the AJAX response is empty. In CHROME the AJAX response is returned properly (chunk of text)

Comment: I would first check the MIME type mapping on the server is present for those file types.

Comment: I am using WebSphere Liberty Server 17. How can I check the MIME type? As I mentioned above the server is returning response. Only the XMLHttpRequest is not populated with responseTxt

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular webserver, you'd have to check the documentation. I only mentioned it as something I've occasionally observed where files are not served properly without that, and some browsers seem more sensitive to it thatn others, but it was in IIS that I observed it, so I don't know if Websphere would have the same thing.

Comment: Also since you're overriding the mimeType in your XHR object I wondered if this was because the server wasn't sending a mime type in the response, or not sending the correct one.